# How to integrate Bootstrap collapse and scrollspy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Twitter Bootstrap to create the same page as 
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html

This is what I have right now.
https://jsfiddle.net/uvsq43bb/1/

I am not able to collapse and show all topics together. If I click on one of the elements and then click on "Expand/Collapse all Topics", everything just toggles but what I want is show and collapse all the items together.
And my Scrollspy doesn't seem to work. Any help?

Also any idea how to collapse a column horizontally? I want to collapse the TOPIC LIST when I click the "Hide/Show Topic List" button.

```
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse1" data-target=".multi-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="list-example">Hide/Show Topic List</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne collapseTwo collapseThree">Expand/Collapse all Topics</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `jQuery`:

```js
$("#toggleBtnBtn").click(function(){
    $("#toggleBtnList").toggle("slow") 
});

$("#toggleBtnList").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("collapsed")
    if($(this).hasClass("collapsed")){
        $("[id^='collapse']").show("slow") 
    }
    else $("[id^='collapse']").hide("slow") 
})

$("[id^='head").click(function(){
    var val = $(this).find("button").data("target")
    $(val).toggle("slow")
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<p>
 <button id="toggleBtnBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse1" data-target=".multi-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="list-example">Hide/Show Topic List</button>
  <button id="toggleBtnList" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Expand/Collapse all topics</button>
</p>


<div>
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-4">
      <div id="list-example" class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#collapseOne">Overview</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#collapseTwo">Introduction</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#collapseThree">Summary</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#list-example" data-offset="0">
<div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Overview
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse multi-collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Introduction
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse multi-collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Summary
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse multi-collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```